# WPF Scrolling content horizontally

Tags: wpf, panel, horizontal-scrolling

I need to create a panel, which layouts some elements from left to right. There is a lot of elements, so scrollbar is needed.
I could use StackPanel+ScrollViewer, but ScrollContentPresenter inside the ScrollViewer clips my elements on top and bottom.
No clipping near the top and bottom borders of the panel is important for me. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I could provide you a solution but first show us, what you've tried.

Comment: Please share screenshot of your problem so that we can help.

Comment: I was digging google for some custom ContentPresenters instead of ScrollContentPresenter. But it seems to be tightly related to ScrollViewer.

Comment: Another idea was to use built-in scrolling of a StackPanel. But it's a logical scrolling. It's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ons, I'm not able to make a screenshot right now. All I need is setting ClipToBounds="False". But it does not work with ScrollViewer.

Comment: How much is it clipping it by? It might be trying to reserve space for the Horizontal ScrollBar, so you may need to adjust the margins or padding by the height of the ScrollBar. Also, can you share your XAML? It's hard to tell if the clipping is the result of your XAML or not if we can't see your code :)

Comment: It seems to be a standart behavior for all the panels. Except the Canvas. Here is an example of xaml:

        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="False" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
            <Button Content="test" Width="100" Height="100" />
            <Button Content="test" Width="100" Height="100" />
            <Button Content="test" Width="100" Height="100" />
            <Button Content="test" Width="100" Height="100" />
        </StackPanel>
Any ideas how to force buttons to be drawn outside the containing panel?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the adorner layer. Thanks to all.